# Setting the value of an Access combobox with VBA comparison

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to figure out where I went wrong with this.

I have two tables `Request` and `Parent`. `Request` can only have one related `Parent` record, but `Parent` can have many related `Request` records. So I have the `Request` table containing the foreign key to `Parent`.

I have an unbound combobox that pulls it's data from the `Parent` table using a query (contains company name and ID bound to column 0 and 1, with column 1 being hidden so the user doesn't see the numeric ID). It's unbound because the form's recordset has a lot of complex joins, making anything on that form unable to be updated. So I created an "On Change" event on the combo box to fill in the foreign key using a querydef SQL update query:

```
Private Sub Combo217_Change()
Dim ComboID As String
Dim ReqID As Long
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim qdfUpdateParentExisting As DAO.QueryDef

ReqID = Me.RequestID.Value
ComboID = Me.Combo217.Column(1)

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set qdfUpdateParentExisting = dbs.QueryDefs("UpdateReqExistingParent")
qdfUpdateParentExisting.Parameters("VBParent").Value = ComboID
qdfUpdateParentExisting.Parameters("VBReqID").Value = ReqID
qdfUpdateParentExisting.Execute
qdfUpdateParentExisting.Close
DoCmd.Save acForm, "DT2"
Me.Requery

End Sub
```

This works just fine, but once you exit the form and re-enter it, the value in the combo box is blank and I would like this to contain the same value that was selected.

I've been trying to do an "On load event" with the following code but it's not working

```
Dim ParID
ParID = Me.ParentID.Value
Me.Combo217.Column(1).Value = ParID
```

Any input on getting this to work would be fantastic!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's tied to specific column you can loop thru to set the value based on the matching ID

> EDIT - Add Row index to Column Value

```
Dim i as Integer

With Combo217
   For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
      If .Column(1, i).Value = ParID Then
         .Value = .ItemData(i)
         Exit For
      End If
   Next
End With
```

Comment: I currently have Column 0 Bound to "Company Name" and Column 1 (This is hidden) Bound to the ID of the Parent table. If I use your method then the Combo box displays the numeric ID instead of the company name. So I guess I want to display Column 0's value, by using Column 1 to select it

Comment: Ahhh okay .. I changed my loop check - does that work better?

Comment: Getting somewhere. It's giving an "Object required" error, but it looks like the itemdata is seeing the correct value in the column. Trouble shooting now

Comment: `If .Column(1).Value = ParID Then`
The ParID variable and Itemdata(i) are both returning the respective values

Comment: Nope, same error. It's strange because the loop clearly see's the object and the itemdata is pulling the correct value from that column (Not to mention the loop is able to count all the items in the list). It's the end of the day so Imma have to troubleshoot a bit more tomorrow with a fresh mind. Thanks for the input! Looks like it's on the right path.

Comment: Hmm - just tested on my system and it works.- add some debug.print statements

Comment: Okay found out the issue! I removed `.value` from `If .Column(1, i).Value = ParID Then` and that worked.