# MSAccess - Pre-Select Combobox Row

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an access form with a combobox on the MainForm.  I am able to set the rowsource as normal.

Request:  Based on a user-selection event in a subform, I want to pre-select the corresponding row in the Combobox to match his selection.  The subform selection would provide the PK value necessary to make a unique combobox row selection - comparing to the value in myCombo.Column(3).

The selected Combobox value drives the recordsource in yet another subform on my mainform.  This part is working as desired, but only after an explicit combobox row selection by the user.

Can this pre-select action be done in VBA?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would review this question and answer ;
[Setting the value of an Access combobox with VBA comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39355475/setting-the-value-of-an-access-combobox-with-vba-comparison)

Which should get you where you need to be.

Comment: Thanks, this approach worked for me after a couple small tweaks.